# Update several records with a foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I have a problem with a part of the code in which, through a foreach I go through an array and those that meet certain conditions are updated by an UPDATE value. The problem is that I try to pass the values ​​with a hidden input and only update the last value. How can I modify the code so I can do it with arrays?

```
try {
    $add = "UPDATE calculo SET puntaje_fecha=:puntaje_fecha WHERE id_calculo=:id_calculo";
    $d = $conn->prepare($add);
    $d->bindParam(':puntaje_fecha', $_POST['puntaje_fecha']);
    $d->bindParam(':id_calculo', $_POST['id_calculo']);
    $d->execute();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br>on line: " . $e->getLine() . "<br>on file: " . $e->getFile());
}
```

---

```
<form action="actualizar.php" method="post">
      <?php foreach ($ca as $c){?>
        <?php foreach ($pr as $p) {}?>
      <?php if (($p['id_fecha'])==($c['nFecha'])){
        //actions to be taken if the conditions are met

                  }?>

                  <input type="hidden" name="puntaje_fecha" value="<?php echo $s; ?>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="id_calculo" value="<?php echo $c['id_calculo']; ?>">

      <?php }} ?>

      <input type="submit" value="Actualiza puntos">
    </form>
```

What I need is that in my "calculo" table all the values ​​of "puntaje_fecha" are updated as long as they meet that condition. Many people have recommended me to change the name of the input by arrays, but I do not know how to do it. Thank you very much to anyone who can help me.

Comment: You are creating your form in a loop, but the `name` attribute of the generated fields is the same, that's why you only get the last value

Comment: Exactly, I know that the error is there. The problem is that I do not know how to do to be able to carry out that part of my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating only two inputs with the names of "puntaje_fecha" and "id_calculo".
So value from last iteration is posted, in order to post all values change the hidden inputs to array.

```
          <input type="hidden" name="puntaje_fecha[]" value="<?php echo $s; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="id_calculo[]" value="<?php echo $c['id_calculo']; ?>">
```

Make sure your inputs look like below by inspect element, otherwise check your data in $ca and $pr

```
          <input type="hidden" name="puntaje_fecha[]" value="value_1">
          <input type="hidden" name="id_calculo[]" value="value_1">
          <input type="hidden" name="puntaje_fecha[]" value="value_2">
          <input type="hidden" name="id_calculo[]" value="value_2">
          <input type="hidden" name="puntaje_fecha[]" value="value_3">
          <input type="hidden" name="id_calculo[]" value="value_3">
```

In your try block through foreach update each value in array.

```
try {

  $puntaje_fechaArray = $_POST['puntaje_fecha'];
  $id_calculoArray = $_POST['id_calculo'];

  foreach ($puntaje_fechaArray as $key => $val){


    $puntaje_fecha = $val[$key];
    $id_calculo = $id_calculoArray[$key];

    $add = "UPDATE calculo SET puntaje_fecha=:puntaje_fecha WHERE id_calculo=:id_calculo";
    $d = $conn->prepare($add);
    $d->bindParam(':puntaje_fecha', $puntaje_fecha );
    $d->bindParam(':id_calculo', $id_calculo);
    $d->execute();
 }

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br>on line: " . $e->getLine() . "<br>on file: " . $e->getFile());
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But where you say add the hidden input I can not understand. I can't change it one by one because the number of fixes in the table will vary constantly while the preogram is running. Sorry if I do not understand, the arrays are complicated for me.

Comment: @MarcosAlborelli Change the name of inputs to  "puntaje_fecha[]" and "id_calculo[]" it will create multiple inputs as an array depending upon the length of array in foreach, Moreover use foreach in your try block as you will receive data as array.

Comment: `<?php foreach ($ca as $c){?>
        <?php foreach ($pr as $p) {}?>
      <?php if (($p['id_fecha'])==($c['nFecha'])){
        //actions to be taken if the conditions are met

                  }?>

                  <input type="hidden" name="puntaje_fecha[]" value="<?php echo $s; ?>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="id_calculo[]" value="<?php echo $c['id_calculo']; ?>">` 
I understand, I only have the question of what to do with the $ca

Comment: You do not need to do any thing further with $ca, as you are already traversing through it by using foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your below code

```
<input type="hidden" name="puntaje_fecha" value="<?php echo $s; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="id_calculo" value="<?php echo $c['id_calculo']; ?>">
```

for this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="puntaje_fecha[]" value="<?php echo $s; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="id_calculo[]" value="<?php echo $c['id_calculo']; ?>">
```

The above treats the input forms as an array so in your controller get the data as follows:

```
$puntajes = $_POST["puntaje_fecha"]; //array
$idsCalculo = $_POST["id_calculo"];  //array
```

You can build the query with a simple foreach:

```
foreach($puntajes as $index => $puntaje) {
    updateData($puntaje, $idsCalculo[$index]); // call the new function for update
}

function updateData($puntaje, $idCalculo) {
   $add = "UPDATE calculo SET puntaje_fecha=:puntaje_fecha WHERE id_calculo=:id_calculo";
    $d = $conn->prepare($add);
    $d->bindParam(':puntaje_fecha', $puntaje);
    $d->bindParam(':id_calculo', $idCalculo);
    $d->execute();
    $message = '';
      if ($d->execute()) {
        $message = 'DATOS ACTUALIZADOS';
      } else {
        $message = 'ERROR DE ACTUALIZACION';
      }

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br>on line: " . $e->getLine() . "<br>on file: " . $e->getFile());
}
}
```

I hope I've helped

Comment: Thanks so much, I have a single doubt. `foreach($puntajes as $index => $puntaje) {
    updateData($puntaje, $idsCalculo[$index]); // call the new function for update
}` Where should I add it?

Comment: Ok ok replace your current foreach for mine and I suggest to create a new function in your current script named updateData($puntaje, $idsCalculo[$index]); that it'll called inside of the foreach function.